# Ruby - Find characters inside brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a string in Ruby. I need to iterate through the brackets in the string.

My String:

```
(((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT)
```

First Iteration should return:

```
((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT
```

Second Iteration should return the below:

```
(MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT
```

Third Iteration should return the following text:

```
MILK AND SOYA
```

How to do this in Ruby? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You must give more complex examples in your question. Your question is not complete enough to make a full implementation.

Comment: For example, what is supposed to happen given this: (((MILK AND SOYA) OR (NUT AND SOYA)) AND COCONUT OR (MILK AND COCONUT))?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923850/boolean-search-in-rails Please refer to my question in the above link. For that Boolean search only i asked this question for splitting the search term. I don't know where to start with my Boolean search. Please suggest

Comment: What you want is a full text search engine for Rails. Google "rails full text search". For example Sphinx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## gsub and regex

@DmitryCat's solution works fine with your example, but it seems you might be interested in the innermost brackets first.

So you'll need to make sure the characters between brackets aren't brackets :

```
str = "(((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT)"

while str.gsub!(/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/){ p $1; ''}
end
# "MILK AND SOYA"
# " OR NUT"
# " AND COCONUT"
```

With `"((MILK AND SOYA) OR (MILK AND NUT))"`

it outputs :

```
# "MILK AND SOYA"
# "MILK AND NUT"
# " OR "
```

## Boolean logic to tree

### With parser gem

Regexen probably aren't the right tool for this job.

This [`parser` gem](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) would have no problem analysing your expression :

```
require 'parser/current'

str = "(((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT)"

p Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(str.gsub(/\b(and|or)\b/i){|s| s.downcase})

# s(:begin,
#   s(:and,
#     s(:begin,
#       s(:or,
#         s(:begin,
#           s(:and,
#             s(:const, nil, :MILK),
#             s(:const, nil, :SOYA))),
#         s(:const, nil, :NUT))),
#     s(:const, nil, :COCONUT)))
```

You now have a tree : a Root node and `children` method. Which you can call recursively to get any information about your expression.

### With sexp gem

(Thanks to @Casper for this suggestion)

It looks like [`sexp` gem](https://github.com/dryruby/sxp.rb) might also work, possibly with an easier syntax than `parser` :

```
require 'sxp'
p SXP.read("(((MILK AND SOYA) OR (NUT AND SOYA)) AND COCONUT)")
# [[[:MILK, :AND, :SOYA], :OR, [:NUT, :AND, :SOYA]], :AND, :COCONUT]
```

## Sphinx

As mentioned by @Casper in the comments (thanks again!), you're trying to reinvent the wheel. If you need full text search for Rails with boolean expressions, [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is a great tool. It's fast, good, reliable and there's an adapter for Ruby/Rails : [thinkingsphinx](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/).

Comment: Great answer. It's perhaps worth mentioning that this type of parenthesized expression is generally called an S-expression. Once you know that you find all sorts of cool and fancy gadgets. For example the `sexp` gem parses OP expressions really nicely. https://github.com/dryruby/sxp.rb

Comment: Your first comment is 1/3 of my answer, so thanks again. Can the `sexp` gem work with infix operators or should `"MILK AND SOYA"` be converted to `"(AND MILK SOYA)"`?

Comment: Actually. Good question. I didn't notice that because I just focused on the parse tree it returned. Not sure.

Comment: Ex: `SXP.read "(((MILK AND SOYA) OR (NUT AND SOYA)) AND COCONUT)"`
=> `[[[:MILK, :AND, :SOYA], :OR, [:NUT, :AND, :SOYA]], :AND, :COCONUT]`.

Comment: @Casper: Do you want to write your own answer? You have more than enough material now.

Comment: @Casper: Shoot, it's not what I meant at all. I'd be happy to include your comments into my answer : I just didn't want you to feel cheated if I pack two of your comments into my answer.

Comment: Ah..ok :) No I don't feel cheated. On SO the early bird gets the worm, and the lazy commenter doesn't get anything. That's how it works! :)

Answer (score 4):

thy this solution:

```
str = "(((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT)"
while not str.nil?
    puts str = str.match(/\((.*)\)/).to_a.last
end # => 
((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT
(MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT
MILK AND SOYA
```

regex `/\((.*)\)/` searches for string inside brackets

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. But is not working if the search term is changed to be like "(MILK AND SOYA) OR (MILK AND NUT)" - This is returning me MILK AND SOYA) OR (MILK AND NUT only. But it should return me "MILK AND SODA" and "MILK AND NUT". How can i get this to work?

Comment: @SuriyaPrabha I think it's the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Use index to get the first character '(' and rindex to find the closing character ')':

```
s = "(((MILK AND SOYA) OR NUT) AND COCONUT)"
s = s.slice(s.index('(') + 1, s.rindex(')') - 1) unless s.index('(').nil? || s.rindex(')').nil?
```

With this code you will get all the string you need. Just call it in a loop until s is nil

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. But is not working if the search term is changed to be like "(MILK AND SOYA) OR (MILK AND NUT)" - This is returning me MILK AND SOYA) OR (MILK AND NUT only. But it should return me "MILK AND SODA" and "MILK AND NUT". How can i get this to work?